# Is there a way to loop backwards after finding a certain line in a txt doc?

Tags: python

I am working with using excel data to edit parts of large txt files. Some of these edits require deleting certain sections, and other require copying, pasting, and slightly editing these sections.

For example, the txt doc takes this basic form:

```
Monitor 1
Monitor 2
Item1 Item2
End

Monitor 3
Monitor 4
Monitor 5
Item3 Item4
End

Monitor 6
Item4 Item5
End
```

Say I am needing to delete the second block (that is, delete from after the first end to the line before monitor 6). I am able to find the block using lookups for Item3 and Item4. Is there a way to assign this block to a variable?

```
with open(longStr1) as old_file:
    lines = old_file.readlines()
    with open(endfile1, "w") as new_file:
        for line in lines:
            if "Item3 Item4" in line:
                #block = from previous End to after next End
                lines.remove(block)
            new_file.write(line)
```

So ideally, this would allow me to delete the entire block of text to make the txt file then look like this:

```
Monitor 1
Monitor 2
Item1 Item2
End

Monitor 6
Item4 Item5
End
```

How can I define this block using python?

Comment: are there any other lookup rules? Does each block always start with `Monitor` ?

Comment: yes, every block starts with monitor, has an unknown number of monitors, and ends with end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterative approach:

```
search_item = "Item3 Item4"

with open('input.txt') as f_in, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    block = ''
    for line in f_in:
        if block:
            block += line
            if line.strip() == 'End':
                if search_item not in block: f_out.write(block + '\n')
                block = ''
        elif line.startswith('Monitor'):
            block = line
```

`output.txt` contents:

```
Monitor 1
Monitor 2
Item1 Item2
End

Monitor 6
Item4 Item5
End
```

Comment: The output is correct, but how would I write this output to the new_file? I've tried to poke on that a little bit but haven't gotten it to work yet. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @jrwaller, tried replace `print(block)` with `new_file.write(block)` ?

Comment: You are right, I had just figure that out myself. To keep the space between the blocks I used `new_file.write(f"{block}\n")`

Comment: Is there a way to make this work where the whole document doesn't follow this pattern? for example, mine has several lines of text, then `BASE CASE' followed by the monitor sections.

Answer (score 0):

You could accumulate the lines to write in a separate string that corresponds to the content of one block. Wait until you reach the end of the block ("end" line) before writing the accumulated lines.  If along the way, you find the text pattern that indicates suppression of the block, set a flag that will prevent writing to the file when the end is reached.

For example (not tested):

```
with open(longStr1) as old_file:
    lines = old_file.readlines()
    lineBlock = ""
    excluded  = False
    with open(endfile1, "w") as new_file:            
        for line in lines:
            lineBlock += line
            if line == "End":
                if not excluded:
                    new_file.write(lineBlock)
                lineBlock = ""
                excluded  = False
            if "Item3 Item4" in line:
                excluded  = True
```

Comment: I know this was just an example, I have not been able to get this concept to work though. The best I can get is it to create a new black txt file. Any further thoughts?